# Make a method call reactive in angular-meteor

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

I am not subscribing the collection but calling a method on server to return some part of collection. how can i re call a method again if there is any update on database and make the returned collections data sync with the server back-end mongoDb, without calling explicitly.
i.e call autorun method if there is any change in database...
is it possible. Please be kind and answer. I am new at meteor.

Thanks

Comment: can you add a code sample? how do you subscribe to the collection?

Answer (score 0):

Would 'getReactively' do the trick? Take a look at http://www.angular-meteor.com/api/1.3.2/get-reactively.

As it is said at [API Reference](http://www.angular-meteor.com/api/1.3.2/):

> Use this method to get a context variable and watch it reactively, so each change of this variable causes the dependents (autorun, helper functions and subscriptions) to run again.